# Gnome Files (Nautilus) very slow to start on Debian Testing (Buster)

Tags: debian, gnome, nautilus

I am experiencing problems to start Gnome Files (Nautilus) on Debian Testing (Buster). I noticed that after an upgrade (I don't know which) Nautilus started to delay some seconds to run.

Running from console I found this error messages:

```
** (nautilus:23814): WARNING **: 18:19:23.023: Error on getting connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying

(nautilus:23814): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 18:19:33.241: g_dbus_connection_signal_unsubscribe: assertion 'G_IS_DBUS_CONNECTION (connection)' failed

(nautilus:23814): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:19:33.241: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

(nautilus:23814): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 18:19:33.241: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that if you delete `~/.cache/tracker/` the problem is solved.

Comment: Here I am, 2½ years later having this same problem. This solved it! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help you!

Comment: Can you explain why you are deleting some cache folder? Unfortunately, it didn't help in my case